# Have the empires of old perished?

Tags: history, gentiles

I remember being taught when I was younger that the fact that Jews are around is a testimony to the eternity of our religion; that we survived them all and that they are no longer.

I am unaware (probably in ignorance) of a source in chazal that justifies this teaching. Perhaps the "v'hee she'amdah" of the haggadah bares resemblance: "that which stood for our forefathers and us, that not only one (nation) stood up against us to destroy us. Rather in every generation and generation they stand against us to destroy and Hashem saves us from their hands".

But is there a more direct source?

Comment: …besides [Mark Twain](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mark+twain%22+jews), you mean?

Comment: http://www.simpletoremember.com/articles/a/7-wonders-of-jewish-history/ references a few sources (secular)

Comment: It seems that the text of this question asks something different from the title. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Daniel, that's why I edited it. If you think it's still too disconnected, feel free to [edit it further](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/28176/edit).

Comment: @SethJ, I actually think that some of the parts that you edited out match the title better than the parts that you left in. Is the question supposed to be about how we have survived, or is it supposed to be about whether the other empires still exist? The title suggests the latter.

Comment: @Daniel, I did not edit out parts of the body. I mainly edited the title.

Comment: @SethJ, Oh I was confusing your edit with msh210's edit.

Comment: http://ohr.edu/yhiy/article.php/2055

Comment: The question is twofold. 1) have the 'empires of old' disappeared? can their ideologies be considered still present. 2) how does this impact the idea that Jews exclusively are eternal since ancient ideologies are still around. Furthermore, there seem to be sources telling of how 'well' the Jews are doing in comparison to those that 'preceded them' and are no longer. One could equally argue that the Jewish 'empire' is also over i.e. temples destroyed, rife assimilation. The parts now edited out give emphasis to both of these questions.

Comment: @user2670 Are those questions that can be answered with facts and references, or questions that lead to opinions and discussions?